# Scrollview not working while using xib custom view in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi I am new for developing ios application.
I have used cocopods framework for doing the page segmentation control.
I have used following mentioned Cocopods [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) framework.

In that Its working fine able to use that pageMenu. In that we need to create the xib customview for doing page menu. so In that framework mentioned with tableview so its able to scroll the page. so I have changed instead of using tableview I have used some form details like ( register page ). so I need to add more textFields for that page.In that scroll not happening. please anyone help for fixing the problem.

Comment: Add your code and  screen shot what you are trying to do?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748997/ios-table-style-textfield-for-login-screen

Comment: Hi.. I need to just use that custom xib with scrollview